# How to apply shadowtext to a whole document

Tags: fonts, shadows

I found the shadowtext package quite useful.

```
\usepackage{shadowtext}
```

However, it only seems to work with parenthesis and ignores line breaks:

```
\shadowtext{Shadow text\\ no line break}
```

How can I apply it to a whole document and paragraphs with line breaks?

Comment: This is not supported by this package. Your line-break case could be reported to Yori Zwols <yz2198@columbia.edu>. To edit the whole text, you would have to ask for a completely new feature. If you just want to change some block of text, put it in a `minipage`, this works. I do not want to imagine a whole document typeset like this... If you really want to have it like this, you should search for some ready built font with shadows and use it via `fontspec`.

Answer (score 1):

Just to show my last comment with some font I have found on my machine (there are many fonts free for download on the web):

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
\setmainfont{ALGER.TTF}
\noindent
Shadow text\\ with line break
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great! Is there something close to `Source Sans Pro`?

Comment: @FrankBreitling No idea. Please search the web or ask on http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/typography